# Mysql Transaction: Effect on other Transaction query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design, transactions

I am writing an application which shall track the financial transactions (as in a bank), to maintain the balance amount. I am using `Denormalizing` technique to keep the performance in check(and not have to calculate the balance at runtime) as discussed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373968/database-design-calculating-the-account-balance) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341883/should-the-users-account-balance-be-stored-in-the-database-or-calculated-dynami).

Now, I am facing a `Race Condition` if two people *simultaneously* did a transaction related to same entity, the balance calculation as discussed above, shall return/set inconsistent data, as discussed [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026825/php-mysql-how-to-prevent-two-requests-update) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13926075/how-to-properly-avoid-mysql-race-conditions), And also as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18455001/807104) in the answers..

I am going for `Mysql Transactions`.

Now My question is,

### What Happens to the other similar queries when a mysql Transaction is underway?

I wish to know if other transactions fail as in `Error 500` or are they *queued* and executed, once the first transaction finishes.

I also need to know how to deal with the either result from the `php` point of view.

And since these transactions are going to be an element of a larger set of operation in php with many prior `insert` queries, should I also device a mechanism to roll-back those successfully executed queries too, since I want `Atomicity` not only as in individual queries but also as in whole operation logic(php).

**Edit 1 :-**
Also, if former is the case, should I check for the error, and wait a few second and try that specific transaction query again after some time?

**Edit 2 :-**
Also `Mysql Triggers` is **not** an option for me.

Comment: i hope there is no *real* money involved here

Comment: No, but the point system we have is none the less, it eventually goes on to be withdrawn in real cash, but a manual verification is in place, and the cash can only be withdrawn offline.

Comment: Whatever answer you get - the only important point is: If your bank will implement your code,  Do you trust your code to always work correctly with your bank account?

Comment: If you are materializing balance amount for performance purposes (and easier overview), then you don't let X possible processes do that. You have only one do it, ever. Therefore, no race condition can occur. You have multiple tools at your disposal - queues, mysql event scheduler to do it on a time basis etc. It's difficult to steer you properly in the right direction since the whole accounting you're dealing with is unclear.

Comment: @RyanVincent Of Course, I sure do 'trust' my code, and as I explained in the question, I am striving to make it least erroneous as possible, while all the input validation taken care of, I am now pondering over the points where an error might creep in, and at the moment this seems to be the point. Thanks though, for your comment.

Comment: @N.B. Well, yeah. That is exactly what I am doing, the balance part is just one query, but there are various preceeding queries like if a customer purchased some product,

Add the product to that customers shopping cart so a query for that (query1), Deduct the no of product available(query2), deduct the amount from that users balance(query3), credit the amount in system balance(query4) something similar...

Comment: Wasn't trying to be obtuse - you need to be sure that your code works with money correctly - always, Speed is not important - accuracy is. That I should have made clear. Ok, 'speed' is 'nice as well'.

Comment: Usually the other applications are locked out or see the unchanged data , depends on what kind of transaction you are doing.

Comment: @N.B. Also the race condition I mention of is what if two users did the same thing, its better explained in this questions second paragraph. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026825/php-mysql-how-to-prevent-two-requests-update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With code like this, there is no race condition.  Instead, one transaction could be aborted (ROLLBACK'd).

```
BEGIN;
SELECT balance FROM Accounts WHERE acct_id = 123 FOR UPDATE;
if balance < 100, then ROLLBACK and exit with "insufficient funds"
UPDATE Accounts SET balance = balance - 100 WHERE acct_id = 123;
UPDATE Accounts SET balance = balance + 100 WHERE acct_id = 456;
COMMIT;
```

And check for errors at each step.  If error, ROLLBACK and rerun the transaction.  On the second time, it will probably succeed.  If not, then abort -- it is probably a logic bug.  Only then should you give `http error 500`.

When two users "simultaneously" try to do similar transactions, then one of these things will happen:

- The 'second' user will be stalled until the first finishes.
- If that stall is more than `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, your queries are too slow or something else.  You need to fix the system.
- If you get a "Deadlock", there may be ways to repair the code.  Meanwhile, simply restarting the transaction is likely to succeed.

But it will *not* mess up the data (assuming the logic is correct).

There is no need to "wait a second" -- unless you have transactions that take "a second".  Such would be terribly slow for this type of code.

What I am saying works for "real money", non-real money, non-money, etc.; whatever you need to tally carefully.

Comment: Thanks for answering, you mean to say, that the queries shall be queued internally(since my queries shouldn't take more than a few micoseconds), and the end users shall not have to re initiate the query, and it will all be seamless when viewed from outside?

Comment: "Lock wait" is seamless, except for an imperceptible delay.  "Deadlock" is fatal to one of the transactions, hence the need to check for errors and replay the `BEGIN...COMMIT`.  The example I gave could deadlock if one connection is moving 'money' from account#123 to 456, and _simultaneously_ another connection is moving money the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks once again, your feedback was of great help.